# Adobe Flash crashes Opera Browser

Tags: browser, flash, opera

Since I updated the flash player (version 10 or something like that), my Opera browser keeps crashing when viewing some sites that have Flash ads. It's really annoying...

Does this happen to anyone else? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: Did you try clearing your history, cookies, [flash cookies](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html), etc?

Comment: I tried that link, and Opera still crashes... For example, sometimes when I'm my yahoo mail page the browser quits and get that send crash report message... Also I disabled plugins for the yahoo page, but I still see flash ads there wtf?

Comment: it seems to be fixed after the latest flash update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not happening to me, and I'm a heavy Opera user.  Try creating an extra profile and see if that solves it, if it does then it means that there's something odd in your main (current) profile.

One of my good friends (who also uses Opera) couldn't view Flash videos on BNN.ca and creating a new profile was what resolved it (clearing cookies and cache wasn't enough to fix this).  Transferring bookmarks and speed dial data was all we needed to do after creating the new profile.